# Измерение магнитной индукции сенсорами смартфона

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10, windows-phone-8

Я не сильна в физике и, в связи с этим, у меня возник вопрос о том, как программно реализовать измерение магнитной индукции сенсорами мобильных устройств? В частности, как можно реализовать это на устройствах на базе Windows Phone и Windows 10 Mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К магнитометру на Windows 10 Mobile можно легко получить доступ с помощью такого простого кода:

```
var magnetometer = Windows.Devices.Sensors.Magnetometer.GetDefault();
if (magnetometer != null)
{
    magnetometer.ReportInterval = 500;
    magnetometer.ReadingChanged += (Magnetometer sender, MagnetometerReadingChangedEventArgs args) =>
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("X: {0}   Y: {1}   Z:{2}", args.Reading.MagneticFieldX, args.Reading.MagneticFieldY, args.Reading.MagneticFieldZ);
    };
}
```

Как из данного вектора получить гауссы или теслы, оставлю для исследования Вам.

Проверял на Lumia 950, подносил неодимовый магнит (достаточно мощный), магнитометр начинает реагировать на него сантиметров с 15, но данные меняются немного стохастически (но меняются 100%).

С большой степенью вероятности, будет работать и на других W10M телефонах.

Касательно же точности и чувствительности сенсора, встроенного в телефон, я не уверен (нет данных); если есть потребность в высокой точности, то, боюсь, придется использовать внешний высокоточный сенсор с микрокопьютером типа RaspberyPi (а связь с телефоном организовать через TCP/IP или BT).